# When does a positive operator preserve invertibility

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $\Omega_1,\Omega_2$ be compact Hausdorff spaces and let $P:C(\Omega_1)\longrightarrow C(\Omega_2)$ be a unital positive operator. I wanted to know if there is a necessary and sufficient condition for $P$ to be an invertibility preserving operator?

Comment: Are you interested in the property that *positive* invertible functions are mapped to invertible functions, or in the stronger property that general invertible functions are mapped to invertible functions?

Comment: @Jochen Glueck Hello, I am interested in the stronger property that general invertible functions are mapped to general invertible functions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The situation you describe is quite general - so I'm not sure whether this has a good answer in this generality. One easy situation, though, is when $\Omega_1$ is connected: then every invertible continuous function has fixed sign and hence, $P$ maps every invertible function to an invertible functions in this case. (Edit: Ah well, this only works in the case of real scalars, of course. Are you interested in real or complex scalars?)

Comment: @JochenGlueck Hi.I am interested in complex scalars. Also as in our discussion on the other post. Any help if $P$ is bounded?

Comment: Positive operators between spaces of continuous functions (or more generally, between Banach lattices) are automatically bounded, so boundedness is not an additional assumption in your setting (nor in the [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/374737/102946) you mentioned).

Comment: In the complex case, $P$ is invertibility preserving iff it's a homomorphism. This follows from the following facts. (1) $P$ is a homomorphism iff $\delta_x\circ P$ is a point measure for every $x\in\Omega_2$. (2) For any probability measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$ that is not a point measure, there is an invertible $f\in C(\Omega)$ such that $\mu(f)=0$. For (2), consider the unitary function $\exp(\pi i h)$ for some $h\in C(\Omega)$ with $0\le h\le 1$ that approximates an appropriate indicator function and do some cosmetics. Details omitted.

Comment: PS. I learned that it generalizes to commutative semisimple Banach algebras over $\mathbf C$, see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=226408

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Thank you for the information.